# Text extraction from pdf file bytes in flutter web

Tags: javascript, typescript, flutter, text-extraction

Anyone knows how to extract text from pdf bytes in flutter web? The syncfusion_flutter_pdf package can do this but its not open source and To use this package, you need to have either a Syncfusion commercial license or Free Syncfusion Community license. So any other alternative?

I tried with js package to read typescript function from flutter web but when i try to import the pdf-parse library and then convert the file to ES5 javascript, the code is:

```
import * as PDFParser from 'pdf-parse';

async function extractTextFromPdf(pdfBytes: Uint8Array): Promise<string> {
    try {
        const pdfData = Buffer.from(pdfBytes);
        const options = {}; // You can pass options here if needed
        const data = await PDFParser(pdfData, options);
        return data.text;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error extracting text:', error);
        throw new Error('Error extracting text');
    }
}
```

and tried to convert this to ES5 with this command:

`tsc --target ES5 extractPdfText.ts`

then get the error shown below:

```
error TS1259: Module '"/pdf_extractor/node_modules/@types/pdf-parse/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import PdfParse from "pdf-parse";
         ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/pdf-parse/index.d.ts:1:1
    1 export = PdfParse;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.


Found 1 error in PdfTextExtractorWeb.ts:1
```

Comment: update you question. errors shouldn't be in screenshots!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).